# MessageBox in c++ using string

Tags: c++, forms

I am getting an error on the following code and I can't figure it out.

```
string name1 = om->get_name();
if (om->search(name, code))
{
    MessageBox::Show("name"+name1);
}
else
    MessageBox::Show("such a car doesn't exist");
```

Gives me the following error

> error C2665: 'System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show' : none of the 21 overloads could convert all the argument types

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing in a `std::string` when you should be passing in a managed `String^`.

Either convert om->get_name() to return a managed `String^` or use the Win32 `MessageBox` function directly (which takes `LPCTSTR` parameters).

Reference for System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3(v=vs.110).aspx

Reference for Win32 API MessageBox function is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx